# How to crop image with css when viewed from mobile phone?

Tags: html, css

I have an image and for desktop view, its height is set to 100vh so it covers the full page. I want to do the same thing for mobile view and set its view to 100vh but its stretched out vertically and looks bad. I think it is because its ratio is 4:3 and wider. I would like to know if there are any ways by which images can be clipped or cropped somehow with css. Image size is 1900px X 1200px

/* ********************* mobile view**************** */

```
 .myimage {
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
```

/* ********************* desktop view**************** */

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .myimage {
     min-height: 100vh;
   }
  }
```

How do i crop the image in the mobile view from the center if lets say i want to crop 30% from each side and only want to keep the middle. Please let me know if there is a best way to approach this without cropping.

Comment: background-image: contain; ? with a max-height of 100vh;

Comment: my picture is not a background image

Comment: can you add some of the html? you should have the image inside `<div>` and give it the `height:100vh` then make the image `height:100%`

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best solution is object-fit property (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)

```
.myimage {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```